# Filling with Values from Following Date in DB upon Join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I effectively need to fill entries that don't exist with the next available data in the archive.

Background: So I've got a record where it has archived each status per month. However it only updates whenever there is a new value, and saves the old value to the previous month. Using MySQL v8.

**How do I fill out the missing values in the table with data with the same ID from the next filled out time period?**

Everything with `archivesDate='2019-08-01'` has NULL data in it intentionally. It implies that the next month is when the data starts.

The middle 3 with `archivesDate='2019-09-01'` needs to be filled out with the next data with the same statusID in the future; in this case it is from `archivesDate='2019-10-01'`. This could be October, or November, or any point in the future. It just needs to fill out with the next value.

**What I've Tried**, but it's only a join on the ID which is why September is showing as `NULL`.

```
SELECT
    al.statusID,
    sa.statusDate,
    sa.statusFlagsID,
    sa.statusPrice,
    al.archivesDate
FROM (
    SELECT 
        sid.statusID AS statusID,
        a.archivesID AS archivesID,
        a.archivesDate AS archivesDate
    FROM (
            SELECT 
                DISTINCT statusID 
            FROM statusArchive) sid
            CROSS JOIN archives a) al
LEFT JOIN statusArchive sa
    ON sa.statusID = al.statusID --This needs to be changed to get next value in cases where there is no value available
        AND sa.archivesID = al.archivesID --This needs to be changed to get next value  in cases where there is no value available
ORDER BY al.archivesDate, al.statusID
```

**Current Output**:

```
statusID statusDate statusFlagsID statusPrice archivesDate
1                                              2019-08-01
2                                              2019-08-01
3                                              2019-08-01
1                                              2019-09-01
2                                              2019-09-01
3                                              2019-09-01
1        2018-10-01  1            37           2019-10-01
2        2018-11-05  1            90           2019-10-01
3        2019-01-01  1            3            2019-10-01
```

**Desired Output**:

```
statusID statusDate statusFlagsID statusPrice archivesDate
1                                              2019-08-01
2                                              2019-08-01
3                                              2019-08-01
1        2018-10-01  1            37           2019-09-01
2        2018-11-05  1            90           2019-09-01
3        2019-01-01  1            3            2019-09-01
1        2018-10-01  1            37           2019-10-01
2        2018-11-05  1            90           2019-10-01
3        2019-01-01  1            3            2019-10-01
```

EDIT: Added mock-up source tables (with all the information to provide the above):

**Source Data**

ARCHIVES

```
archivesID       archivesDate
1                2019-08-01
2                2019-09-01
3                2019-10-01
```

STATUSARCHIVE (replace s with status in the following column names, SO formatting issue sorry)

NB: Missing entries from `archivesID=2`

```
sArchiveID  sID  sFlagsID  sPrice  sDate       archivesID
1           1    NULL      NULL    NULL        1
2           2    NULL      NULL    NULL        1
3           3    NULL      NULL    NULL        1
4           1    1         37      2018-10-01  3
5           2    1         90      2018-11-05  3
6           3    1         3       2019-01-01  3
```

And **DB-Fiddle** [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=RUtgc58Loo) and the SQL to create data source:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE archives (
  archivesID INT,
  archivesDate DATE
);
INSERT INTO archives (archivesID, archivesDate) VALUES (1, '2019-08-01');
INSERT INTO archives (archivesID, archivesDate) VALUES (2, '2019-09-01');
INSERT INTO archives (archivesID, archivesDate) VALUES (3, '2019-10-01');

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE statusArchive (
  statusArchiveID INT,
  statusID INT,
  statusFlagsID INT,
  statusPrice DECIMAL,
  statusDate DATE,
  archivesID INT
);
INSERT INTO statusArchive (statusArchiveID, statusID, statusFlagsID, statusPrice, statusDate, archivesID) 
    VALUES (1, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1);
INSERT INTO statusArchive (statusArchiveID, statusID, statusFlagsID, statusPrice, statusDate, archivesID) 
    VALUES (2, 2, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1);
INSERT INTO statusArchive (statusArchiveID, statusID, statusFlagsID, statusPrice, statusDate, archivesID) 
    VALUES (3, 3, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1);
INSERT INTO statusArchive (statusArchiveID, statusID, statusFlagsID, statusPrice, statusDate, archivesID) 
    VALUES (4, 1, 1, 37, '2018-10-01', 3);
INSERT INTO statusArchive (statusArchiveID, statusID, statusFlagsID, statusPrice, statusDate, archivesID) 
    VALUES (5, 2, 1, 90, '2018-11-05', 3);
INSERT INTO statusArchive (statusArchiveID, statusID, statusFlagsID, statusPrice, statusDate, archivesID) 
    VALUES (6, 3, 1, 3, '2019-01-01', 3);
```

Comment: What does the output look like?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen added better formatting to clarify

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Sample data and a db fiddle would be really helpful.  I am baffled where the values are coming from.

Comment: @Strawberry how's this now?

Comment: @GordonLinoff now with DB-Fiddle and clarified wording

Comment: An immeasurable improvement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fast fix: Translate your comment into code.

```
AND sa.archivesID = al.archivesID -- This needs to be changed to get next value
                                  -- in cases where there is no value available
```

becomes

```
AND sa.archivesID = (
    SELECT MIN(x.archivesID)
    FROM statusArchive x
    WHERE x.statusID = al.statusID
      AND x.archivesID >= al.archivesID
)
```

Full query:

```
SELECT
    al.statusID,
    sa.statusDate,
    sa.statusFlagsID,
    sa.statusPrice,
    al.archivesDate
FROM (
    SELECT 
        sid.statusID AS statusID,
        a.archivesID AS archivesID,
        a.archivesDate AS archivesDate
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT statusID FROM statusArchive) sid
    CROSS JOIN archives a
) al
LEFT JOIN statusArchive sa
    ON  sa.statusID = al.statusID
    AND sa.archivesID = (
        SELECT MIN(x.archivesID)
        FROM statusArchive x
        WHERE x.statusID = al.statusID
          AND x.archivesID >= al.archivesID
    )
ORDER BY al.archivesDate, al.statusID
```

Result:

```
| statusID | archivesDate | statusDate | statusFlagsID | statusPrice |
| -------- | ------------ | ---------- | ------------- | ----------- |
| 1        | 2019-08-01   |            |               |             |
| 2        | 2019-08-01   |            |               |             |
| 3        | 2019-08-01   |            |               |             |
| 1        | 2019-09-01   | 2018-10-01 | 1             | 37          |
| 2        | 2019-09-01   | 2018-11-05 | 1             | 90          |
| 3        | 2019-09-01   | 2019-01-01 | 1             | 3           |
| 1        | 2019-10-01   | 2018-10-01 | 1             | 37          |
| 2        | 2019-10-01   | 2018-11-05 | 1             | 90          |
| 3        | 2019-10-01   | 2019-01-01 | 1             | 3           |
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/foiMa2vKFXbYiNAXui1JgF/0)

Note: You should have an index on `statusArchive(statusID, archivesID [other columns])`.

The following (shorter) query also works for the given sample data:

```
select 
  s.statusID,
  s.statusDate,
  s.statusFlagsID,
  s.statusPrice,
  a.archivesDate
from archives a
left join statusArchive s
  on s.archivesID = (
    select min(x.archivesID)
    from statusArchive x
    where x.archivesID >= a.archivesID
  )
order by a.archivesDate, s.statusID;
```

For this query you should have an index on `statusArchive(archivesID)`.

Result:

```
| statusID | statusDate | statusFlagsID | statusPrice | archivesDate |
| -------- | ---------- | ------------- | ----------- | ------------ |
| 1        |            |               |             | 2019-08-01   |
| 2        |            |               |             | 2019-08-01   |
| 3        |            |               |             | 2019-08-01   |
| 1        | 2018-10-01 | 1             | 37          | 2019-09-01   |
| 2        | 2018-11-05 | 1             | 90          | 2019-09-01   |
| 3        | 2019-01-01 | 1             | 3           | 2019-09-01   |
| 1        | 2018-10-01 | 1             | 37          | 2019-10-01   |
| 2        | 2018-11-05 | 1             | 90          | 2019-10-01   |
| 3        | 2019-01-01 | 1             | 3           | 2019-10-01   |
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/t33pTheZYF3poXqZeaW8KN/0)

However - I don't know if this will return the desired result on any possible data set, because I can only guess the exact requirements from your sample data and result.

#### Update

If you need the next row ordered by the corresponding `archivesDate`, you will need an `ORDER BY ... LIMIT 1` subquery:

```
SELECT
    al.statusID,
    sa.statusDate,
    sa.statusFlagsID,
    sa.statusPrice,
    al.archivesDate
FROM (
    SELECT 
        sid.statusID AS statusID,
        a.archivesID AS archivesID,
        a.archivesDate AS archivesDate
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT statusID FROM statusArchive) sid
    CROSS JOIN archives a
) al
LEFT JOIN statusArchive sa
    ON  sa.statusID = al.statusID
    AND sa.archivesID = (
        SELECT x.archivesID
        FROM statusArchive x
        JOIN archives y ON y.archivesID = x.archivesID
        WHERE x.statusID = al.statusID
          AND y.archivesDate >= al.archivesDate
        ORDER BY y.archivesDate ASC
        LIMIT 1
    )
ORDER BY al.archivesDate, al.statusID;
```

Make shure you have indexes on

- `statusArchive(statusID [, other columns])` for `x.statusID = al.statusID` aswell as for `SELECT DISTINCT statusID FROM statusArchive`
- `archives(archivesID, archivesDate, [, other columns])` for the conditions `y.archivesID = x.archivesID` and `y.archivesDate >= al.archivesDate` and the ORDER BY clause `y.archivesDate ASC`.

Comment: Just tested it, also works if I change one of the archive IDs to 4 which points to a later date also. Great work, thanks!

Comment: how would I join this on the minimum archivesDate instead?

Comment: There is no `archivesDate` in `statusArchive`. Do you mean minimum `statusDate`?

Comment: As per question it needs to be by date in case the ID is not in order. There's an archivesID which joins to the Archives table to get the date...

Comment: so by archivesDate (which archivesID refers to), I've added an edit which I hope is approved.

Comment: Something like [this](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xoR9YLfb6UbdLxgzKLH6y4/0)?

Comment: Yes, precisely. Thanks for your help. Add that to the answer. I'll accept and send through the bounty. Thanks again!

Comment: My key learning is that you can take the `al.statusID` and use the alias within brackets, that still makes it line by line. And the fact that the alias scope does this means it can still be done line by line. Brilliant! Thanks.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your last comment. In SELECT, WHERE and ON clauses you can use [*correlated subqueries*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/correlated-subqueries.html), which can reference columns from the *outer* query.

Comment: OK, correlated subqueries is the term. Thanks for this!